# How to interpret the set $\{x\mid x \in A \implies x \in B \}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> How to interpret the set $\{x\mid x \in A \implies x \in B \}$?

I've seen it in exercises from a few texts, but it isn't obvious to me. Thanks.

Comment: Which texts for instance?

Comment: Surely $\{x|x\in A \subset B\}$. I don't see the big problem.

Comment: In a purely logical sense, it means the union of $B$ and the complement of $A$.

Comment: @simplicity I doubt it. That notation makes it seem like $A\subset B$ which implies the set is just $A$ whereas in the original notation it just has to make sense to take the intersection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This (unconventionally) defines the set
$$B\cup(A^c).$$
Hint: the assertion $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to $Q\lor(\lnot P)$.

Comment: Of course, if $A$ and $B$ are sets, and we aren't implicitly working inside some ambient set, then $B \cup (A^c)$ will not actually be a set, but rather a proper class.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, thank you.

Comment: I have never seen the notation $A^c$ before. Where is it used?

Comment: @ndroock1 "I have never seen the notation Ac before." [Really?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))

Comment: Kindly asking for a book reference where it is used, dear Oracle of knowledge.

Comment: @ndroock1 Did you notice the link in my previous comment?